# Show the measurability of a left continuous map

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a distribution on $\mathbb R ^n$ and let $X$ be a random variable with $\mathbf{P}_X=\mu$. Then $\kappa (x,\cdot)= \mathbf{P}[X+x \in \cdot]$ defines a stochastic kernel from $\mathbb R ^n$ to $\mathbb R ^n$. Indeed, the sets $(-\infty,y], y \in \mathbb R ^n$ form an $\cap$-stable generator of $\mathcal B(\mathbb R ^n)$ and $x \mapsto \kappa (x,(-\infty,y])=\mu ((-\infty,y-x])$ is left continuous and hence measurable. Hence, $x \mapsto \kappa (x,A)$ is measurable for all $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R ^n)$.

---

My doubt: Honestly speaking, I don't really understand why we can infer the measurability of $\mu$ simply from the left continuity of $\mu$, what I know is that the continuity of a map always implies its measurability, so can someone explain it to me in detail? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g: \mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R$ be left continuous and define $g_m(x)=g(\frac {i_1-1} {2^{m}},\frac {i_2-1} {2^{m}},...,\frac {i_n-1} {2^{m}})$ if $\frac {i_j-1} {2^{m}} \leq x <\frac {i_j} {2^{n}}$ for all $j$. Then $g_m$ is measurable for each $m$ and $g_m(x) \to g(x)$ as $m \to \infty$ for every $x$.

Note that each $g_m$ takes constant values on measurable sets and hence it is Borel measurable.

Comment: I think I have understood your construction of the $g_m$,but excuse me,what does it mean "$g_m takes constant values on measurable sets$"?Did you want to mean that $g_m$ takes some constant value on every neighborhood of each $x \in \mathbb R^n$ with radius small enough?Thank you!

Comment: $g_m$ takes constant values on sets of the type $A_1\times A_2\times...\times A_n$ where each $A_i$ is an interval of  the real line. Since these sets are Borel sets, $g_m$ is Borel measurable.  @RH_L